# TFS Work Item HyperLink from TextBox

Tags: tfs

Im trying to create a hyperlink on my form that has the URL specified in another field.

I found the Link control which can almost do this, but i dont see a way to configure it use the URL specified in another field.

Something like this might work, but i would have a double https:// in the url.
Is there a way to take a substring of the value so that i can remove the https part ?
Or is there another way to add a link to the work item form that uses the URL from another field.

```
<Link UrlRoot="https://" UrlPath="{0}">
   <Param Index="0" Value="Custom.UrlField" Type="Original"/>
</Link>
```

Using the HTML field would in theory also be an option, but only if we can hide the HTML buttons and use a small height, this way the URL pasted in this field will become a clickable URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not supported. See [Provide help text, hyperlinks, or web content on a work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/provide-help-text-hyperlinks-web-content-form?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json)

You have to specify the URL directly like this:

```
<Link UrlRoot="http://www.live.com"></Link>
```

The syntax to specify a hyperlink with parameters should be like this (See [Link and Param XML elements reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/link-param-xml-elements-reference#example-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-field)):

```
<Link UrlRoot="http://serverName" UrlPath="sites/{0}/render.aspx?wit=bug&amp;topic=Iteration">
   <Param Index="0" Value="System.Project" />
</Link>
```

That means you need to provide the `"http://serverName"`,  **only specify `"https://"` is not working**, reference below screenshot.

In your scenario, we can not get the value of another field to set the hyperlink  in work item form. There's a [Copy Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/define-default-copy-value-field) for fileds, but it's not available for work item form.

> **COPY**  Copies a specified value to a field when a user creates or modifies a work item. See [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming, i am now indeed configuring a base url instead of https://. It works in most cases, but that means we can only point to url's starting with this UrlRoot, which is unfortunate.
Do you have any other suggestions of creating a button/link on the form that can point to the URL in another field ?

Comment: @Nico I don't think we can achieve that, no such an element in TFS WIT definition file. It's **Form** but not work item **Field**, if it's a filed we can use **Copy Rule** to copy the value from another field.

Comment: ok, last one, would it be possible to set a condition on the link ? Say only make it a link if the value != "". or better only make it a link if it does not contain the base URL or something like that ?

Comment: @Nico No, it's not supported, no such rules in TFS, all available rules for work item fileds are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field